# SQL Developer: Need help to identify if data in column changed from Negative to Positive or vice versa

Tags: sql, oracle

My condition/requirement is:
If my numeric value from the given Price column changes from Negative to Positive or vice versa between previous day and day before, then I need to report this data.
Example: When I run the sql for 13-SEP-21, I should get the data from 11th and 12th [because the sign are changing] *** for Ref ID 04 and 02 and if I run the report for 12-SEP-21, then sql should be BLANK; because 10th and 11th have -ve value [no change in the sign]

| Effective Date | Prices | Ref ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10-SEP-21 | -12 | 02 |
| 11-SEP-21 | -15 | 02 |
| 12-SEP-21 | 10 | 02 |
| 11-SEP-21 | -09 | 04 |
| 12-SEP-21 | 05 | 04 |
| 13-SEP-21 | 10 | 03 |

Comment: You mention extracting from SQL Developer - is there some feature of the product that you are using to export data, or do you just mean you are using an Oracle database for reporting? Also you have tagged [PL/SQL Developer](https://www.allroundautomations.com/products/pl-sql-developer/), another desktop tool.

Comment: my apology William. I mean to say, I'm using Oracle SQL Developer tool to write the sql and extract the data.

Comment: 1. What if the price becomes 0? How do you treat that? 2. What if the price is NULL? Or is the column constrained to non-NULL values? 3. What if a date is missing (the dates go from 11-SEP directly to 13-SEP or even 14-SEP etc.)? 4. What is your database version? 5. What if there are three (or more) rows where the sign changes on every row? Do you need each row shown just once, or do you need to show every pair of dates with sign changes (even if that means some dates will be duplicated in the output)?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a good use case for `LAG` and `LEAD` functions.  Take the following example:

```sql
WITH test_data (effective_date, price) AS
(
SELECT DATE '2021-09-10', -12 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-09-11', -15 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-09-12', 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-09-13', 10 FROM DUAL
)
SELECT s.effective_date, s.price
FROM (SELECT td.effective_date, td.price, 
             LAG(td.price) OVER (ORDER BY td.effective_date) DAY_BEFORE, 
             LEAD(td.price) OVER (ORDER BY td.effective_date) DAY_AFTER
      FROM test_data td) s
WHERE s.price*s.day_before < 0
OR s.price*s.day_after < 0
ORDER BY s.effective_date;
```

That query will take the row before and the row after and check for a sign change via simple multiplication.

Here is a DBFiddle showing how this query working, in addition to showing how you could use a `WHERE` clause to limit the dates returned [DBFiddle Link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9d10dfc576a33b7d68c16a1110597777)

Comment: Multiplying the prices is unnecessary (wasteful) - better use `sign(s.price) * sign(s.day_before)`. With some luck the optimizer is able to make this change on its own, but I have some doubts that it's smart enough.

Comment: Thank you, I made a correction apologies this scenario missed before. Added ref id